# Hosoya Triangle in java

Tags: java

Objective: Individually, create a recursive representation of Hosoya’s triangle.

Your task:  Haru Hosoya, a famous mathematician described a triangle (seen below) which is a triangular arrangement of numbers based on the Fibonacci numbers.  Get a height from the user and use an array to store the values on each line.  Print out the appropriate number of levels of Hosoya’s triangle using a recursive method.  Do NOT assume that the input will be good.  You should also implement try…catch blocks to catch erroneous input.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
public class HosoyaTri {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        boolean continueLoop = true;
        int num = s.nextInt();
        do {
            try {
                System.out.println("How many levels?");

                System.out.println(num + " levels");
                continueLoop = false;
            } catch (InputMismatchException im) {
                System.err.println("I said INTEGER, try again");
                s.nextLine();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.err.println("What did you do?");
            }
        } while (continueLoop);
        int triangle[][] = new int[num][num];
        for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < num; j++) {
                triangle[i][j] = 0;
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
            triangle[i][0] = 1;
        }
        for (int i = 1; i < num; i++) {
            for (int j = 1; j < num; j++) {
                triangle[i][j] = triangle[i - 1][j - 1] * triangle[i - 1][j];
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j <= i; j++) {
                System.out.print(triangle[i][j] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: What specific problem are you having? Is your program crashing? Producing incorrect output? Something else?

Comment: I can read in the amount of levels from the user, but cannot actually create the hosoya triangle. If i try to run this program nothing happens but there are no errors

Comment: Looks like homework...

Comment: Something happens on my computer - it prints a triangle, although the values are obviously not correct.. Take care: **Print out the appropriate number of levels of Hosoya’s triangle using a recursive method** - There's no recursion yet.

Comment: im trying to figure where the actual recursion fits in

Answer (score 1):

One problem is that you are reading the number of levels once, before the input loop. You are then prompting for a level and then printing `num` without giving the user any chance to provide input! You should fix that. You should also be testing against `num <= 0`.

As far as how to use recursion goes, the entries in [Hosoya's triangle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosoya%27s_triangle) can be defined recursively:

> H<sub>0, 0</sub> = H<sub>1, 0</sub> = H<sub>1, 1</sub> = H<sub>2, 1</sub> = 1
>   H<sub>n, j</sub> = H<sub>n−1, j</sub> + H<sub>n−2, j</sub> or
>   H<sub>n, j</sub> = H<sub>n−1, j−1</sub> + H<sub>n−2, j−2</sub>

Another (equivalent) definition is:

> H<sub>n, i</sub> = F<sub>i+1</sub> × F<sub>n−i+1</sub>

where F<sub>n</sub> is the n<sup>th</sup> [Fibonacci number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number), defined recursively as:

> F<sub>0</sub> = 0
>   F<sub>1</sub> = 1
>   F<sub>n</sub> = F<sub>n-1</sub> + F<sub>n-2</sub> (n > 1)

I would suggest using one of these definitions to write a (recursive) static method in your class that calculates the correct value for one entry in the triangle (given `n` and `j` as arguments). Then you can eliminate the `triangle` variable and all the code that initializes it. Simply run your output loop and substitute a call to the recursive method where you now access a specific element of `triangle`. (If for some reason you need to explicitly build the triangle, simply initialize each element by calling the recursive method. As an aside: there's no need to initialize the elements of `triangle` to 0; Java does that automatically when the matrix is allocated.)

Comment: I will work on it and get back to you, thank you for your help